# How to configure a Swing JFrame as a Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, swing

I have a simple JFrame as the main window of my Java desktop application and I would like to configure it as a Spring bean. I would like to set properties, inject dependencies and launch it. Here's my frame class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        setTitle("Static Title");
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

My Spring application context:

```
<bean class="com.example.MainFrame">
    <property name="title" value="Injected Title" />
</bean>
```

Then I fire it all up...

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
}
```

...which is followed by this `java.beans.IntrospectionException`:

```
type mismatch between indexed and non-indexed methods: location
```

The frame is actually displayed but there's that exception and the title remains "Static Title". So I have a few questions...

I've seen this being [done by IBM in a 2005 tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-springswing/section4.html) but with Spring 1.2, and I don't even know what JRE. So how do I approach this exception? Is it possible to configure a JFrame as a Spring bean or do I need to proxy it or something?

I'm also wary of not launching the application from the event dispatching thread. So if there's a cleaner way of doing this I'd like to know about it. I can easily dispatch everything except that I don't know how to dispatch the construction itself.

Finally feel free to criticise the overall concept. I haven't come across many examples of Spring managed Swing applications. I'm using Spring-3.1 with Java-1.6.

Thanks.

Comment: You can look at [Spring Rich Client](http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/index.html) to get some idea. I am not sure if this would help you. I had heard about this project somewhere.

Comment: I was wary of touching Spring RCP as it hasn't had a release since 2009?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, looks like its inactive now.

Comment: This does seem a little weird ;) Are you using Spring to create other parts of the GUI too? i.e. to wire up the various JPanels, etc that the main frame uses.

Comment: @AngerClown It's part of a much larger, distributed application with numerous layers and instances that are wired up with Spring, including IoC, MVC and Remoting. It almost seems silly not to use Spring in the frontend too as we have it everywhere else!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, and it seems that's actually a bug on Spring: 
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8491

I think I'll wrap a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) around the panel and see if it works. I'll edit this post later, in case it works (or not)

-- edit --

Okay, instantiating it through a FactoryBean does get around the problem. The declaration becomes a little awkward, but that will have to do, at least until the aforementioned bug is fixed.

```
package com.ats.jnfe.swing;

import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

/**
 * Contorna, em caráter temporário, o bug apontado em:
 * https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8491
 * Quando o erro acima for resolvido, esta classe estará obsoleta.
 *
 * @author HaroldoOliveira
 */
public class SwingFactoryBean<T> implements FactoryBean<T> {

    private Class<T> beanClass;
    private Map<String, Object> injection;
    private String initMethod;

    private Map<String, PropertyDescriptor> properties;
    private BeanInfo beanInfo;
    private Method initMethodRef;

    public T getObject() throws Exception {
    T t = this.getBeanClass().newInstance();

    if (this.getInjection() != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> en : this.getInjection().entrySet()) {
        try {
            this.properties.get(en.getKey()).getWriteMethod()
                .invoke(t, en.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException(MessageFormat.format(
                "Error initializing property {0} of class {1}",
                en.getKey(), this.getBeanClass().getName()), e);
        }
        }
    }

    if (this.initMethodRef != null) {
        this.initMethodRef.invoke(t);
    }

    return t;
    }

    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
    return this.getBeanClass();
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
    return false;
    }

    public void initialize() {
    try {
        this.beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(this.getBeanClass());
        this.properties = new HashMap<String, PropertyDescriptor>();

        PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = this.beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : descriptors) {
        this.properties.put(pd.getName(), pd);
        }

        if (this.getInitMethod() != null) {
        this.initMethodRef = this.getBeanClass()
            .getMethod(this.getInitMethod());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BeanInitializationException(
            "Error initializing SwingFactoryBean: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    }

    public Class<T> getBeanClass() {
    if (this.beanClass == null) {
        throw new BeanInitializationException("Class not informed.");
    }
    return this.beanClass;
    }
    public void setBeanClass(Class<T> beanClass) {
    this.beanClass = beanClass;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getInjection() {
    return injection;
    }
    public void setInjection(Map<String, Object> injection) {
    this.injection = injection;
    }

    public String getInitMethod() {
    return initMethod;
    }
    public void setInitMethod(String initMethod) {
    this.initMethod = initMethod;
    }

}
```

Usage example:

```
<bean id="certificadoNFeConfiguracaoDialog" class="com.ats.jnfe.swing.SwingFactoryBean" init-method="initialize" scope="prototype" lazy-init="true">
<property name="beanClass" value="com.ats.ecf.view.swing.util.dialog.OKCancelDialog" />
<property name="initMethod" value="inicializa" />
<property name="injection">
    <map>
    <entry key="selector">
        <bean class="com.ats.jnfe.swing.SwingFactoryBean" init-method="initialize">
        <property name="beanClass" value="com.ats.jnfe.swing.CertificadoNFeConfigPanel" />
        <property name="initMethod" value="inicializa" />
        <property name="injection">
            <map>
            <entry key="fachada" value-ref="certificadoNFeConfiguracaoFacade" />
            </map>
        </property>
        </bean>
    </entry>
    </map>
</property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Runs with Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE, 3.1.4.RELEASE und 3.2.3.RELEASE.

It seems it has been a bug as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to keep Swing out of Spring. Past anything trivial, wiring up a GUI using something else is going to be too tedious. Instead, I would change what you are doing and just use `main()` to create the Spring content and then create your GUI.

If all you are doing in Spring would be creating the MainFrame and starting it, maybe the easiest thing is to create a `FactoryBean` that creates the frame. The factory could also call `setVisible()` via a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed runs with Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE too.